# How to unselect a range previously selected in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have create a combobox that permit to modify the content some cells in a range selected. After making a choice in the combobox, I would like to unselect the range that I have selected before. I have make several attempts but I couldn't make it work. Finally I try to call another sub just immediately before the end of the `sub ComboBox1_Change()` but it didn't work, either. Any suggestions?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim operatore As String
    Dim op1 As String
    Dim op2 As String
    Dim trovato As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    operatore = ComboBox1.Value
    op1 = Left(operatore, 3)
    op2 = Right(operatore, 3)
    trovato = 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Non hai selezionato nessun range di celle!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each cell In rng
        If (trovato = 2) Then
            Exit For

        ElseIf StrComp(cell.Value, op1) = 0 Then
            trovato = trovato + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    If (trovato < 2) Then
        MsgBox "Operatori non trovati nella selezione!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Select Case operatore
            Case "Op1<-->Op2"
                For Each cell In Selection
                    If cell.Value = "Op1" Then
                        cell.Value = "Op2"
                    ElseIf cell.Value = "Op2" Then
                        cell.Value = "Op1"
                    End If
                Next cell
                MsgBox "Scambiato Op1 con Op2"
                Set rng = Nothing
            Case "Op1<-->Op3"
                For Each cell In Selection
                    If cell.Value = "Op1" Then
                        cell.Value = "Op3"
                    ElseIf cell.Value = "Op3" Then
                        cell.Value = "Op1"
                    End If
                Next cell
                MsgBox "Scambiato Op1 con Op3"

        End Select
    End If
    unselect rng
End Sub

Public Sub unselect(dataRange As Range)
    Set dataRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Just `Select` something else.

Comment: I would like to avoid to select something else because this can cause other unexpected malfunction for future development

Comment: You cannot un-select how you would like to do it. Something must always be selected: cell, range, object like text box etc.

Comment: Just select another Cell thats not critical like A1 or any other Cell with no content

Comment: Yes, you guys are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Think about using booleans as stored states, then simply use an If to control your method

Answer (score 1):

Or, save state before into variable, like

```
sTemp = Application.Selection.Address

'after all manipulations, restore selection
Application.Range(sTemp).Select

'also, reset copying mode
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```